# How to implement role-based authorization in Blazor WASM without modifying Identity Server code

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly

Before posting this question I' ve done lots of research in the Internet, I' ve found some stuff, but I wasn't able to find something that fits my case.
So please provide me the right direction or code snippets to go on.

I'm developing an app in .NET 6 which consists of 2 projects: **Blazor WASM** project for the client-side and a **WEB-API project** for the API's of my app.

At the moment, I've successfully implemented authentication from a central **Identity Server 4**. I receive "id_token" and "access_token" and use them to
secure access to my web-APIs from unauthenticated users.

The problem is that now I want to implement "*role-based authorization*". The facts are:

- I cannot modify the code of the common Identity Server I use.
- I have the users, the roles and their connection inside my app's database.

I think that the right solution here is implementing a **MIDDLEWARE** which reads the roles from my database and adds them into the "Claims".

Where should I develop the middleware? Web-Api project, blazor project or both???

If I developed a middleware in the Web-Api project (where by default there is already a pipeline) which adds roles into the Claims of "access_token",
the blazor project wouldn't work bacause of the modified token, right???

Could you help me with code snippets or provide me the right directions?

Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: did you checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this article describes how to configure Identity Server to include extra claims in the token it sends to client. I want to include extra token from my server. I don't have access to Identity Server.

Answer (score 1):

The client sends the access_token in every request. The server validates the access_token and then creates a ClaimsPrincipal with the claims that were included in the token. In your server can add additional claims to the ClaimsPrincipal using the OnTokenValidated event. Example:

```
.AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
{
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async context =>
        {
            var user = context.Principal;
            var userId = user.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            // Get DbContext. If you don't use Entity Framework request your own data access service.
            //var dbContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();

            // Retrieve user roles from database and create a list of role claims.
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin")
            };

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

            user.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity);
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

Then in your controllers you can check for the role using `[Authorize(roles = "admin")]` or `User.IsInRole("admin");`.

Answer (score 0):

Authorization is solely an API responsibility:

- The Blazor app sends up an access token to identify the user, via the subject claim
- The API verifies the JWT on every request, then looks up other claims for that subject
- The extra claims can be cached for subsequent requests with the same access token

My sample .NET API shows one way of doing this and building a custom ClaimsPrincipal. Once you've done that, .NET's standard authorization techniques such as the [Authorize] attribute will work based on the ClaimsPrincipal's contents.

- [Authorizer class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/ClaimsCachingAuthorizer.cs#L33)
- [Blog post](https://authguidance.com/net-core-api-oauth-integration/)

Comment: Please a little help in the theory: After user logging in, the Blazor app receives an "access_token" from the Identity Server. I understand that Blazor app has to include the token in every request and if the token is the same with the one server app (web-api project) has, then the server app will respond. If I added additional claims in the token at the server app, then the token would be differentiated from that in the blazor app. So every request would fail. Is my logic right? What is the thinking to overcome this?

Comment: The server app does not change the access token. Instead it verifies the token on every request, to prove the caller identity. The server app then builds a Claims Principal from the token and uses this data for authorization. If you cannot include all the information you need for authorization in the token, then you can add extra data to the Claims Principal, eg from the server app's database.

Comment: Ok! I got it for the server side! What about the client side? How to authorize my pages based on the additional claims from my app's database? Do I have to create independently from the server a new claimsIdentity for the Authentication state of the client?

Comment: The client side just sends an access token to the API in REST requests. If required you can provide an API endpoint such as /user/claims that returns identity related information to the client in a JSON response. The UI can then decide which UI elements to show based on that data.